# To filter out whitespaces in pictures in LaTeX

Tags: latex

**Problems:**

1. to make the picture a coordinate system such that you can apply functions to it
2. to make a "detection" algorithm which first tries to find the objects like in "ship sinking" -game by considering pixels such that a failure in detecting a white-pixel causes the algorithm look at the pixel in the opposite site in the square.

**An example of an inefficient algorithm**: if the square (100,100) and a pixel at (1,1) is white, then the new pixel to look at is (99,99), then (1,99), then (99,1), then (50, 50), then (50, 0), then (0,50), ...

I have pictures which are large because they contain much unnecessary whitespaces.

An example of such picture is
[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/kasitekaavio.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/kasitekaavio.png)

**How can you scrape out the unnecessary whitespace?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using pdfcrop (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfcrop/) that hopefully is present in your TeX installation.

Answer (score 1):

Google says:
http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial5.html
Down the bottom is an example of how to crop an image.

A forum post about the same thing:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2467&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a